# Controllers with setup in init function are always equal

Tags: ember.js

I've an `Ember.Controller`, with setup-code in the init function. In reality this code makes AJAX requests.
But when I create two instances of this controller, they are always equals. Why, and what can I do again this?

I've made this simple example, which shoud write `Test 1` `Test 2` into the console. Bit its writing `Test 2` twice.

```js
App = Em.Application.create({});

App.TestController = Em.Controller.extend({
    content: Em.Object.create({
        info: null,
    }),
    init: function() {
        if(this.id == 1)
        {
            this.content.set('info', "Test 1");
        }

        if(this.id == 2)
        {
            this.content.set('info', "Test 2");
        }
    },
});

var c1 = App.TestController.create({id: 1});
var c2 = App.TestController.create({id: 2});

console.log('C1: ' + c1.get('content').get('info'));
console.log('C2: ' + c2.get('content').get('info'));


​
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to set `content` value in `init`, otherwise, the value set at class declaration time will be shared by all instances.

```
App.TestController = Em.Controller.extend({
  content: null,

  init: function () {
    this._super();
    this.set('content', Em.Object.create({
      info: null
    }));

    // other setup here...
  }
});
```

See http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/

Comment: Hm, I see. But is this a bug and will be fixed, or is this the Idea?
If its a feauture, whats the reason?

Comment: It is part of Javascript / Ember's Object model. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/462. Probably will never change...

Comment: Also don't forget to call `this._super();` inside your custom `init` function ...

Comment: @pangratz Absolutely true! Thanks for the precision.